# Question about Java's BigInteger's toString

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger

Java's BigInteger's toString use recursive algorithm,

```
toString(BigInteger u, StringBuilder sb,
                                 int radix, int digits)
```

it divides u into ranges of radix,radix^2,radix^4,radix^8(basically radix^2^n),

```
int b = u.bitLength();
        int n = (int) Math.round(Math.log(b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]) /
                                 LOG_TWO - 1.0);
```

then decides u falls into which range and use divideAndRemainder to concatnate the result
(it's a recursive algorithm)

```
BigInteger v = getRadixConversionCache(radix, n);
        BigInteger[] results;
        results = u.divideAndRemainder(v);

        int expectedDigits = 1 << n;

        // Now recursively build the two halves of each number.
        toString(results[0], sb, radix, digits - expectedDigits);
        toString(results[1], sb, radix, expectedDigits);
```

the confusing part to me is, why it uses

```
Math.round(Math.log(b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]) /
                                 LOG_TWO - 1.0)
```

I think it should use floor, and without - 1.0

```
Math.floor(Math.log(b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]) /
                                 LOG_TWO)
```

to find the proper radix^2^n to divide,
also I take from 2 to 1024 for a test(2^1 to 2^10)

```
[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
```

if using

```
Math.round(Math.log(b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]) /
                                 LOG_TWO - 1.0)
```

then it becomes

```
[-3, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

which seems wrong,
but using

```
Math.floor(Math.log(b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]) /
                                 LOG_TWO)
```

the result is

```
[-2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

which seemed correct

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. What `radix`  did you use for your calculations? Also note that this code is only executed if `u.bitLength()` is at least 672 (as indicated by the preceding `if (u.mag.length <= SCHOENHAGE_BASE_CONVERSION_THRESHOLD) {..}`)

Comment: I'm using radix 10, yes, u.bitLength() should be at least 672 to trigger the recursive algorithm, but anyway, it should be correct when computing the index into getRadixConversionCache, the problem is, floor is absolute correct, where round and - 1 is very confusing

Answer (score 6):

**What is the purpose of that code?**

The purpose is to find a `BigInteger v` that has the form `radix^x` that divides the `BigInteger u` into two parts that have a string representation of roughly the same length. The "perfect" value for that would probably be 10^x where `u.sqrt()` is between `0.5 * 10^x` and `5 * 10^x` (for radix 10). However such a calculation would be highly inefficient.

(Maybe the factors 0.5 and 5 are not ideal - maybe they should be 0.316 and 3.16 so that 100 is choosen for values from 1000 to 100000 - but as this approach is not used the exact values don't matter.)

Instead the code approximates that "perfect" value by using a value from the sequence radix^1, radix^2, radix^4 because these radix^(2^x) values are easy to calculate and still give good enough results.

Lets see how that calculation works for a `BigInteger` with a bitlength of 1024 (which has a string representation of length 308 to 309 characters).

The expression `(int) Math.round(Math.log(b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]) / LOG_TWO - 1.0)` is two calculations wrapped into one expression:

- `b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]` calculates the approximate number of digits to represent the `BigInteger` value as string in radix `radix`

  Note that `logCache[radix]` is initialized with `Math.log(radix)` and `LOG_TWO` is `Math.log(2)`, so the full expression is `b * Math.log(2) / Math.log(radix)`

  For a `bitlength` of 1024 this calculation gives 308.2547 (rounded to 4 digits).

  Lets name this intermediate result `num_digits`
- The second calculation is then `(int) Math.round(Math.log(num_digits) / Math.log(2) - 1.0)`. For `num_digits` of 308.2547 this gives 7.

  Therefore in our example the code will pick `10^(2^7)` (which is 10^128) as divisor to split the original number.

**Why does it use `Math.round(x-1)` instead of `Math.floor(x)`?**

*Note that this example uses a very small `bitlength` just to prove the point. Effectively this calculation is never done with so small values*

It gives a better value for `n`.

Take for example a bitlength of 14 (the `BigInteger` value is between 8192 and 16383).

Using `Math.round(Math.log(b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]) / LOG_TWO - 1.0)` gives n=1, which means the code will choose `10^(2^1)` (which is 100) to split the `BigInteger`.

Using `Math.floor(Math.log(b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]) / LOG_TWO)` gives n =2, which would mean that the code would choose `10^(2^2)` (which is 10000) to split the `BigInteger` - but for a `BigInteger` value of 8192 that would mean it would not split it at all.

*Using `Math.floor()` breaks down at several places:*

- for the values 64 - 127 (bitlength = 7) using `Math.floor()` results in n=1 and u=100 and therefore cannot split values 64-99
- for the values 8'192 - 16'383 (bitlength = 14) using `Math.floor()` results in in=2 and u=10'000 and therefore cannot split values 8'192 - 9'999
- for the values 67'108'864 - 134'217'727 (bitlength = 27) using `Math.floor()` results in in=3 and u=100'000'000 and therefore cannot split values 67'108'864 - 99'999'999
- for the values 9'007'199'254'740'992 - 18'014'398'509'481'983 (bitlength = 54) using `Math.floor()` results in in=3 and u=10'000'000'000'000'000 and therefore cannot split values 9'007'199'254'740'992 - 9'999'999'999'999'999

For those ranges (and there exist other ranges at larger bitlength values) you would need special handling after the split: if the upper part is BigInteger.ZERO then do some special handling. But any kind of special handling makes the algorithm more complex, more error prone and slower.

*For other ranges using `Math.floor()` doesn't really give better results than using `Math.round()`:*

- for the values 16'384 - 99'999 (bitlengths from 15 to 17) using `Math.floor()` results in in=2 and u=10'000 and therefore the values are split into 1 digit and 4 digits.

  Using `Math.round()` for these values results in n=1 and u=100 and therefore the values are split into 3 digits and 2 digits which to me seems more equally split.
- for the values 100'000 - 262'143 (bitlengths from 17 to 18) using `Math.floor()` results in in=2 and u=10'000 and therefore the values are split into 2 digits and 4 digits.
  Using `Math.round()` for these values results in n=1 and u=100 and therefore the values are split into 4 digits and 2 digits.

  For this range both approaches are on an equal level - either way you have a 4 digit number that you need to split further.

**Why is that special case handling such a problem**

Lets try to convert the number 659'876 into a decimal string.

Both approaches (using Math.floor() and using Math.round()) agree that we should use n=2 and u=10'000 in the first step.

Using the calculation with Math.floor():

- in the first step 659'876 is split into 65 and 9'876

  - recursion 1: 65 - is a special case, needs additional work to split it into 6 and 5
  - recursion 2: 9'876 - is a special case, needs additional work to split it into 98 and 76

    - recursion 2.1: 98 - is a special case, needs additional work to split it into 9 and 7
    - recursion 2.2: 76 - is a special case, needs additional work to split it into 7 and 6

(the last recursive step that appends the single digit values to the StringBuilder has been left out).

Using the calculation with Math.round():

- in the first step 659'876 is split into 65 and 9'876

  - recursion 1: 65 is split into 6 and 5
  - recursion 2: 9'876 is split into 98 and 76

    - recursion 2.1: 98 is split into 9 and 7
    - recursion 2.2: 76 is split into 7 and 6

**Example using 16'383**

One of your comments claims that 16'383 cannot be handled using Math.round(), so lets take this as additional example.

Using the calculation with Math.floor():

- in the first step 16'383 is split into 1 and 6'383

  - recursion 1: 1 is appended to the StringBuilder
  - recursion 2: 6'383 is split into 63 and 84

    - recursion 2.1: 63 is split into 6 and 3
    - recursion 2.2: 83 - is a special case, needs additional work to split it into 8 and 3

(the last recursive step that appends the single digit values to the StringBuilder has been mostly left out).

Using the calculation with Math.round():

- in the first step 16'383 is split into 163 and 83

  - recursion 1: 163 is split into 16 and 3

    - recursion 1.1: 16 is split into 1 and 6
  - recursion 2: 83 is split into 8 and 3

As you can see even when using `Math.round()` its no problem to convert 16'384 into a decimal string.

**Conclusion**

Using `Math.floor()` doesn't work for all cases (i.e. requires additional logic to detect those cases and then needs to do additional work). IMHO this observation is enough to reject that approach.

Note that you could "fix" the algorithm using `Math.floor()` by subtracting a small value from the `num_digits` intermediate result. But then, `Math.floor(xx-0.5)` gives for most values of xx the same result as `Math.round(xx-1.0)`.

Hooray, we found a way that we could use `Math.floor()` without needing a special case handling! :)

**Additional note**

This calculation doesn't work for very small values of bitlength.

In the case of radix 10 it doesn't work for bitlength less than 4 - but bitlength values from 1 to 3 mean that the actual value in the `BigInteger` is in the range from 1 to 7 - and for so small values the algorithm doesn't make sense (because the result is confined to a single digit).

Comment: let's take bitlength of 15 for example, from 16384 to 32767,the Math.round()-1 still yields 1, but it should be 2(10*2**2=10000)

Comment: Also I'm trying to understand your first paragraph, why u would between 0.25*10^2x - 25*10^2x, take 100=10^2 as an example, that means from 2500-250000 would all use 100, so that means 250000 would be divided as 2500(4 digits),00(2 digits), similarly, 2499 would use 10, which 249(3 digits),9(1 digit), which would have 2 digits difference

Comment: test for  bitlength of 16(32768-65535), Math.round()-1 still yields 1, floor yields 2, bitlenght 17(65536-131071),Math.round()-1 still yields 1, floor yields 2,seemed floor yields correct result

Comment: After second thought, your example of bitlength of 14(8192-16383) spans 100(10^2)-10000(10^4), because bitlength of 14 could bit a bit larger, from 10000-16383,then it needs divide by 10000, so floor basically means conservative, it could have some lower end that doesn't exceeds 10^2^n,but in larger end, it will need that value(from 10000-16383), while round() - 1 only yields 1, which means it can handle 8192-9999, the problem is from 10000-16383 it can not handle

Comment: Why should it be unable to handle 10000-16383? With 100 those numbers will be split into a lower part (with 2 digits from 00 to 99) and an upper part (with 3 digits from 100-163). With 10000 those numbers will be split into a lower part (with 4 digits from 0000 to 6383) and an upper part (with a single digit 1). Why should the recursion be able to handle a 4-digit lower part but not a 3-digit upper part?

Comment: oh,I get you point. Basically it means finding the "perfect" n, which gets back to your first paragraph.But I don't understand your first paragraph, why u would between 0.25*10^2x - 25*10^2x, take 100=10^2 as an example, that means from 2500-250000 would all use 100, so that means 250000 would be divided as 2500(4 digits),00(2 digits), similarly, 2499 would use 10, which 249(3 digits),9(1 digit), which would have 2 digits difference

Comment: The bounds in the first paragraph are not perfect. For radix 10 the "perfect" u would used for numbers between 0.1*u^2 and 10*u^2. The next bigger value (u') is 10*u, which would then be used for 0.1*u'^2 to 10*u'^2 (which are the same as 10*u^2 to 1000*u^2)

Comment: yes, now I understand your  first paragraph. Thanks. Now back to algorithm, take bitlength 18(131072-262143) for example, round()-1=round(2.4379)-1=1, where floor(2.4379)=2, (Math.log(b * LOG_TWO / logCache[radix]) /
                                 LOG_TWO yields 2.4379), so floor() seemed give a better value, since using 10000 would be 3 digits + 3 digits, but if using 100, would be 4 digits + 2 digits